# Is the relation transitive when xRy ⇔ ∃k ∈ ℤ: x+y = k , where x, y ∈ ℝ?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I understand this correctly, the relation is not transitive since for example when x=1/4, y= 3/4 and z= 5/4. Therefore x+z ≠ k. Could someone show how to proof this in a formal way?

Comment: Yes, the given relation is not transitive, neither is it reflexive, but it is symmetric.

Comment: In my view your own proof is formal enough. Maybe you should say $x+z\notin\mathbb Z$.